# Is my PHP cURL request malformed because of using a variable in the URL?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Is my PHP cURL request malformed because of using a variable in the URL
The request works fine when I check it without that Variable. How can i fix it?

```
<?php

$search_string = $_POST["search_string"];

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" . $search_string . "&key=AIzaSyDsb0EFY9lde2EcTYKou3Xrz9ax91qiuTY",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error: " . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}

?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($search_string);` to confirm the value is what you expect

Comment: What are you actually seeing?

Comment: urlencode the search string, for one.

Comment: @Jonnix: The Google Answer ist "INVALID REQUEST"

Comment: @PatrickQ var_dump and urlencode has no effect

Comment: @TarekHaddad  The `var_dump()` is not a _solution_, it is to show you the value of the variable.  What is the result of doing `var_dump($search_string);`?  Do you see the value that you expect?

Comment: yes, its the value i expect

Comment: But no Solution

Answer (score 1):

1. Please define constant:

```
define('MYURL',   "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" . $search_string . "&key=AIzaSyDsb0EFY9lde2EcTYKou3Xrz9ax91qiuTY");
```

2. Change  CURLOPT_URL to:
   `CURLOPT_URL => MYURL`

This works for me.

Comment: I fail to see how that would resolve the problem. You're just aliasing a variable to the string and passing it at a parameter. If the issue is with the URL or a cURL variable to begin with, this wouldn't solve anything.

Comment: It's magic :) Cant explain.